# Incorrect subdomain as folder in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to open subdomain as folder, for ex: http://sms-rassilka-cityname.sitename.ru open like http://sitename.ru/cities/barnaul/ (real folder with files)

I used this rules for all cities:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sms-rassilka-cityname\.sitename\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cities/cityname/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/cityname/$1 [L,QSA]
```

But when I change this for universal rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sms-rassilka-([a-z]+)\.sitename\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cities/%1/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cities/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

server fall down for error 500: Internal Server Error.

2d line don't gete paremetr, but in 3d it get.
What's wrong in my rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your rules this way.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sms-rassilka-([a-z]+)\.example\.ru [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!cities/.*).*)$ /cities/%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Very Good! But how to allow get any requested file? http://sms-rassilka-cityname.sitename.ru/files.txt

Comment: Solved by remove qsa flag ) Thanx!